# adding annotations to every bar in bargraph of coreplot

Tags: ios, annotations, core-plot

I used  the barPlot:barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex method to add annotation to every bar but it didn't worked and I used the same code in my method and created the plot object manually and assigned it value of the actual plot as shown below

```
 - (NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot{
    return [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInWeek] count];
    _getplot = plot;
}
```

My Method used for annotation is as below:

```
- (void)SetAnnotations {
    static CPTMutableTextStyle *style = nil;
    if (!style) {
        style = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
        style.color= [CPTColor yellowColor];
        style.fontSize = 16.0f;
        style.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    }

    // 3 - Create annotation, if necessary
    for (int index=0; index<3; index++) {

    NSNumber *price = [self numberForPlot:_getplot field:CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip recordIndex:index];
    if (!self.priceAnnotation) {
        NSNumber *x = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
        NSNumber *y = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
        NSArray *anchorPoint = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:x, y, nil];
        self.priceAnnotation = [[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation alloc] initWithPlotSpace:_getplot.plotSpace anchorPlotPoint:anchorPoint];
    }
    // 4 - Create number formatter, if needed
    static NSNumberFormatter *formatter = nil;
    if (!formatter) {
        formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    }
    // 5 - Create text layer for annotation
    NSString *priceValue = [formatter stringFromNumber:price];
    CPTTextLayer *textLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:priceValue style:style];
    self.priceAnnotation.contentLayer = textLayer;
    // 6 - Get plot index based on identifier
    NSInteger plotIndex = 0;
    if ([_getplot.identifier isEqual:CPDTickerSymbolAAPL] == YES) {
        plotIndex = 0;
    } else if ([_getplot.identifier isEqual:CPDTickerSymbolGOOG] == YES) {
        plotIndex = 1;
    } else if ([_getplot.identifier isEqual:CPDTickerSymbolMSFT] == YES) {
        plotIndex = 2;
    }
    // 7 - Get the anchor point for annotation
    CGFloat x = index + CPDBarInitialX + (plotIndex * CPDBarWidth);
    NSNumber *anchorX = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:x];
    CGFloat y = [price floatValue] + 40.0f;
    NSNumber *anchorY = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:y];
    self.priceAnnotation.anchorPlotPoint = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:anchorX, anchorY, nil];
    // 8 - Add the annotation
    [_getplot.graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea addAnnotation:self.priceAnnotation];
    }
}
```

But it's showing an error as

```
Assertion failure in -[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation initWithPlotSpace:anchorPlotPoint:], /Users/eskroch/Projects/Core Plot/framework/Source/CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation.m:42
2015-05-08 12:16:19.195 CorePlotDemo[871:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: newPlotSpace'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01c8d1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018758e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01c8d048 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x012484de -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
```

Comment: Can any body tell me how to add annotation to every bar in the bar graph in core plot 1.4

Answer (score 0):

The exception is telling you that `CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation` requires a valid plot space when it is created. A plot is assigned to a plot space when you add it to a graph.

Comment: Thank You Eric. The exception problem is solved, but i am still not able to add annotation to every bar in graph, can you help me with this?

Comment: You can add as many annotations as you want. Just make sure they all have different anchor points so they don't stack up in the same place.

Comment: You have to create new annotations each time. In the code in your question, you only create one.

Comment: i tried to add new annotation with different anchor point, but when i add this to plot area the old annotation is removed and the new one is added.

Comment: what i need to do is to show annotations for all the bar as soon as the view is loaded. So, can you please help me with this.

Comment: `priceAnnotation` only holds one annotation. You need to create a new annotation object for each annotation you want to show on the graph. If you need to keep references to the annotations, use a collection like an array or set.

Comment: Skorch Thanks your idea worked i added a new object of plotspaceannotation and added new anchor point to it. now i get annotation to every bar.

Comment: I have an issue with axis labeling i want to add a string value to the axis label but its showing default numerical value.. so, could you please help me with this..

Comment: `NSNumberFormatter` is really flexible. Look at Apple's docs for all of the formatting options. Update your formatter to change the number format for the labels.

Answer (score -1):

> Can any body tell me how to add annotation to every bar in the bar graph in core plot 1.4

This code will add annotations to all bars.

```
        - (void)setAnnotations
        {
            for (CPTBarPlot *theBarPlot in theArrayOfBarPlots)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < [self numberOfRecordsForPlot:theBarPlot]; i++)
                {
                    NSNumber *theNumber = [self numberForPlot:theBarPlot field:CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip recordIndex:i];

                    CPTMutableTextStyle *style = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
                    style.color = [CPTColor yellowColor];
                    style.fontSize = 10;

                    CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation *thePriceAnnotation = [[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation alloc] initWithPlotSpace:theBarPlot.plotSpace anchorPlotPoint:@[@(i), @(theNumber.doubleValue + 30)]];
                    thePriceAnnotation.contentLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", theNumber] style:style];
                    [theBarPlot.graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea addAnnotation:thePriceAnnotation];
                }
            }
        }
```